# PHP or MySQL caches queries

Tags: php, sql, caching

I have a big big problem! I've developed a PHP script that uses many queries to insert, select and delete values from a MySQL database. I never had any problem with it, 'till now. Now it started to display the data from yesterday. If I run an INSERT query through PHP, it displays the real data, but if I go again to that page or any other, it still displays the data from yesterday. The queries are not complicated, just some `SELECT * FROM table` and simple `INSERT` queries. I think something uses cache to run the queries.

I tried `SQL_NO_CACHE`, but same result.

A simple code example that returns data from yesterday.

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM persoane";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
```

What could it be?

LATER EDIT:

There is this script on one of my pages:

```
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
include_once("php_includes/functii.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persoane WHERE status='a' ORDER BY nume";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$data =  date("d-m-Y");

if(isset($_POST['orainceput'])){
    $persid = $_POST['prezpersid'];
    $ora = $_POST['orainceput'];
    $nota = $_POST['notaprez'];
    $autor = $_SESSION['user'];

    $psql = "INSERT INTO prezente (persoana_id, data, ora_inceput, autor, nota) VALUES ('$persid', NOW(), '$ora', '$autor', '$nota')";
    $pquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $psql);

}
```

If the `$_POST['orainceput']` is set and after the query inside is run, everything works just fine: it displays what it should display. If I refresh the page, it displays cached data again. I don't get it! I never had this issue!

Comment: Have you verified any of this? E.g. you have checked the database that the new records are there? And what happens if you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Hi! Yes, the data is in the database and if I clear the browser cache I get the same result. I wasn't talking about browser cache for one simple reason: my client called me and told me about the issue and I went to the app and saw that too. I was thinking about a server-side cache.

Comment: Have you created a minimal app that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I had. Same result. But I managed to solve it, it seems that it was a problem with the hosting server. As I said, it was returning data from a SQL cache.

Comment: So when you verified the database why haven't you seen the cached results?

Comment: Because the database contained the right data, but instead of returning that data to the `SELECT` query, it returned the cached data.

Comment: Please read my question again. How have you verified the database has the right content? `SELECT`? :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is a browser cache. One notable difference between correct/incorrect behaviour is GET vs POST request. Where:

- HTTP POST request is not cacheable; and
- HTTP GET is cacheable.

Depending on browser you use for testing, it might implement very aggressive approach to cacheing. I'd suggest to try anonymous mode, or just clear all caches from browser and try to reload the page. Also trying different browser is an option.

On top of that i'd examine web server configuration to make sure what additional HTTP headers are being send to client and whether there are cache related headers.

Comment: Hi! I didn't say it is a browser cache. I doubt that too, because the client called me and told me about this issue and I went to the webpage and saw that too. I was thinking about a PHP or MySQL cache (any kind of server-side cache). The problem with the POST is that after I run it, everything works just fine and it displays what it should display. The correct data (e.g. new entries) is stored in the database... but not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTTP protocol itself is stateless and a new PHP thread will be initiated each time a page is being loaded, it will not cache any user data, unless you are telling it to do (for example: writing/reading the result of a query into/from a file in the data access layer). MySQL can cache query results, but the query cache entry is automatically purged when a related table accepts any CRUD/DML action which changes the table.

From the MySQL doc:

> If a table changes, all cached queries that use the table become invalid and are removed from the cache. This includes queries that use MERGE tables that map to the changed table. A table can be changed by many types of statements, such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, or DROP DATABASE.

The cache should sit somewhere between the application and the browser: the browser itself, a proxy, etc, or implemented in the application. Check your application and the environment it is running on.

Further references

- More about MySQL caching: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html
- More about HTTP caching: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html